# Simultaneously partition all mesh elements (nodes, edges and cells) among processors

Tags: unstructured-mesh, partitioning

The numerical method that I'm implementing stores various fields in various elements of an unstructured triangular mesh. Data may be stored in cells, nodes and even edges of the mesh. For a parallel implementation I need to distribute all the mesh elements among processors.

There are well known approaches to the problem of distribution cells or nodes, but I failed to find how to distribute all the elements at once.

Of course one can distribute all mesh elements independently by partitioning the corresponding adjacency graphs. But this approach gives no guarantee that the cells of i-th processor and the nodes of the same processor are close (that is cells of i-th processor are mostly composed of the nodes from the same processor).

So I came up with an approach to partition only mesh nodes and then try to partition edges and cells optimally, i.e. minimize cross-processor edges and cells while maintaining a fair distribution. Anyway, a proper implementation is quite tough and has some corner cases.

Do you know any existing solutions to the problem above?

Comment: You might want to look at what PETSc does with DMPlex objects. They must have developed some approach for this problem, I'm just not exactly sure what the details are.

Comment: You can also check the octrees based solution from library called p4est. There is an implementation of the same in deal-ii also.

Comment: The usual approach is to partition cells. Edges and vertices are then assigned to one of the processors who own adjacent cells, often by way of a tiebreaker. For example, if a vertex or edge is adjacent to cells owned by different processors, then the processor with the lowest rank owns the vertex or edge.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!